# Azure VPN Client error: Failure in acquiring AAD Token: Keyset does not exist

Tags: azure, active-directory, vpn, azure-vpn

I followed instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant
And also double checked same instructions here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur0WNjnXJrU

Everything went fine. When I download the Azure VPN Client, and import the xml profile that Azure gave me, I log in, and then i get an error

**Failure in acquiring AAD Token: Keyset does not exist**

[image]

Why is it asking about a keyset? Nowhere did I set up certs. This is Azure AD Authentication type (not Radius and not Azure Certificate type which asks for root certs). So there is no place to select a cert. And the instructions do not indicate a certificate is needed with this Azure AD Authentication type.

Inside the VPN profile azurevpnconfig.xml, I can see a

```
<serversecret>[...]</serversecret>
```

and

```
 <cert>
      <hash>[...]</hash>
      <issuer
        i:nil="true" />
    </cert>
```

where did those come from? I never set up any keys or certs. Is it just part of Azure?

Answer (score 4):

The cause was the cached user/pass on the Microsoft Login. Instead of clicking in my remembered login in the list they provide,  I clicked "Log in as different user", and I was able to log in. This may be due to MFA which is on.

Completely non-helpful error messages though!

Comment: This workaround really works.

Comment: Indeed - very non-intuitive - you bring up the 'account' app - and you can only 'manage' but not remove that account.
Then - you just select IN THE VPN-app to use a new login - and that gets it work.